# Sandboxed code evaluation during a breakpoint session

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, pdb

Say I set a breakpoint on the following `if` statement in my code and launch a debugging session in a Python debugger (e.g. [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)):

```
if <statement> and <...>:  <- Current location of debugger in a debugging session
  // Do something
```

I'd like to **interactively** ask the debugger (in the context of a breakpoint) the boolean value that `<statement>` would return in the program as if I never run that statement before continuing the execution of the program in the context of a debugging session.

Note that `<statement>` may of course change Python variables (mutable values), and moreover, it may **not** be an idempotent operation.

Does VSCode support this type of "safe debugging"? Note that this applies not just to if statements, but any code.

I would assume that these types of debugging inspections may require "snapshotting" all process variables (or those that may be affected by `statement`) just in case, and I don't know if that's something the VSCode debugger (or general modern debuggers) support.

Comment: I am no voice of expert, but using Visual Studio Code integrated debugger I've never run into any trouble.

Comment: do you know of a way to inspect the active object stack or view the value of a condition like just `if <expr>`? I'm not convinced cpython makes the object stack available for a debugger to inspect.

Answer (score 1):

to offer some insight, consider the way this kind of statement is executed:

```
import dis
def f(a, b):
    if a and b:
        print()
dis.dis(f)
```

this compiles down to the following byte code:

```
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       14
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       14

  6           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
```

So setting the breakpoint at the if statement pause before any of the `if` block has executed, in order to read the value of `a` (the first condition) the debugger would need to step forward instructions pausing at the first `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` then read the value at the top of the stack.  In theory this is possible but what is a little odd is that once it advances past the first `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` the value is no longer accessible as that instruction removes it from the stack.

Typically I believe debuggers (at least ones that use breakpoints at line numbers) treat all steps that are on the same line as a single step, so it would execute all instructions until the `LOAD_GLOBAL` in one go which doesn't allow to read intermediate values.